# lld-link:error: failed to write the output file: permission denied

Tags: firefox, build

I'm trying to build the Mozilla Firefox code, and I ran upon this error:

[image: lld-link:error:failed to write the output file: permission denied]

I have asked the people at the Firefox development chatroom, and it seem no one has run into this problem before. I'm new to the open source development, and I don't have much experience in debugging a program like this before. I have looked at the log, and I don't where to start to figure out a problem like this.

Comment: Please post the log output in text form rather than in an image. Also missing from the question: Command(s) used to build, OS name/version, compiler name/version.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a problem with Mozilla's specifically tooled version of clang 11 that is being pulled down through the bootstrap script. Dropping in an older clang version from Mozilla's CI allows one to get past this. Apparently it's linked specifically against Win 10 libraries so likely won't work on Win 7 or 8.

See also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1699228
I've gotten past this with e.g. pulling down clang from https://firefox-ci-tc.services.mozilla.com/api/queue/v1/task/VzRmR7vqQmynv_6T14oguA/artifacts/public/build/clang.tar.bz2 as suggested by Mozilla employee glandium.